# IPhone how to properly resize view when rotating device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation, orientation

I have been trying to resize my view inside a view Controller with no luck so far. Basically I have a button at the very bottom of my view and when the orientation changes from Portrait to Landscape the button is no longer visible, because its just too far down now.

How can I resize this view so that when the orientation changes the button is still visible?. I have tried setting

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

and basically every other possible combination, with no luck so far. I know I can do this by manually repositioning the button, but is there a better way to do this?.

Thank you.

-Oscar

Comment: You should accept good answers to your questions.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that, I think I accepted it now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The view containing the button must be auto-resized using your mask (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`).
2. On the containing view `autoresizesSubviews` must be set to YES.
3. The button must use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`.